# JPA Shared Entity mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a scenario where I have a Object called Page, and another object called Tag, relationship between these two is Page has Tags(many to many), but the same Tags can also shared with Product, here also the relationship is same Product has Tags (many to many).

In normal scenario I will create a type column in Tag where type may be Enum value (product, page) and use query like SELECT * from Tags where parent_id = page_id and type = page.

How to do this in JPA (how to create this relationship and how to query data)

Comment: Question: If the Page->Tag relationship is one to many, then the same tag cannot be used for more than one page and the same applies to Products. Is this the behaviour you want?

Comment: Oh ya sorry its many to many, I will edit my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should create two tables of associations. One to associate Pages with tags, one to associate Products with tags. The code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
class Page {
  ....

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "jnd_pages_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "page_fk"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_fk"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;      
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
class Product {
  ....

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "jnd_products_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "products_fk"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_fk"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;      
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
class Tag {
.....
}
```

to select corresponding tags for page, use

```
SELECT p.t FROM Page p WHERE p.id = :id
```

to select corresponding tags for product, use

```
SELECT p.t FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id
```

Comment: But in case of search items by tags, I need to return products and pages related to that tag then I need to search for 2 tables, later I may introduce one more Object which can be tagged, then it become complicated while searching by tags

Comment: I would rather use inheritance then, you can create some @MappedSuperclass TagContainer, f.e., which will contain Set of tags and id. This way you will be able to use something like `SELECT t FROM TagContainer t JOIN t.tags tag WHERE tag.id= :tagId`